# How to provide an indication for partial success?

Tags: gui-design, indicator, design-principles

I am working on a system where the user configures a complex structure which consist of several layers of composition. When the user completes the configuration he clicks the 'Apply' button and then the system tries to create the structure for him. The issue is that the request may have partial success - where some of the objects configuration succeeded and some where not. In this case, we get that some of the settings on the GUI are inconsistent with the actual configuration. Looking for a way to solve this inconsistency, I see the following options:

1. Override the requested configuration with the actual one, so now the configuration on screen matches the actual.
2. Leave the configuration as-is, do not provide any indication if an object was successfully configured or not.
3. Leave the configuration as-is, but provide an indication if an object was successfully configured or not.

The first two options are provided only for the sake of completeness/explanation. They are bad UX choices, I believe everyone would agree. **The question is how to provide an indication for the partial success result?**

Answer (score 2):

3a. Leave the configuration as-is but provide a completion report showing a numerical summary of completion vs failure as well as details of the items completed and those that failed along with the reasons they failed and suggestions for fixing the errors.