# How to indicate partial success in an Android notification?

Tags: usability, android, notification, states

My question is somewhat similar to this question: [How to provide an indication for partial success?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/99458/how-to-provide-an-indication-for-partial-success) But I need to show the indication as an Android Notification.

A user can send an alarm (calling for help) using a mobile device, however, if the location on the device is turned off, then we want to still send the alarm and show the user a success notification that their alarm was sent, but also tell them that the location was not sent.

**How to indicate this in an Android notification?**

The failed notifications are indicated with a red icon and success ones with a green icon in current design of app.
It is important to show the success but also the fact that its partial.

In terms of color and icon, what is the best approach?

Keep in mind there is a certain character limit to how long messages can be displayed so relying on text only to tell the user that GPS was not sent might not be the best idea (but of course can be used as last resort).

Answer (score 1):

In terms of color, red and green aren't great ways to distinguish two cases when considering red-green color blindness (protanopia|deuteranopia).

In terms of Android Notification guidelines and the System Tray: your icons should not have color. So if you are doing it right, you show the colored icons in the Notification's panel itself (small or large icon).

Why don't you simply add the text "Location was not sent" within the Notification content?

As for the best approach: it really depends on your users. User Testing or AB Testing is probably the best approach for determining the best approach.